# Different alignment of labels in enumerate

Tags: horizontal-alignment

Consider the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% found somewhere on TeX.SX (can't remember where)
\makeatletter
  \def\myitem{\@ifnextchar[\@myitem{\@noitemargtrue\@myitem[\@itemlabel]}}
  \def\@myitem[#1]{\item[#1]\mbox{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}[
  label = \underline{Post~\arabic*},
  leftmargin = *,
]
  \myitem
  \myitem
  \myitem
  \myitem
  \myitem
  \myitem
  \myitem
  \myitem
  \myitem
  \myitem
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

As can be seen, the `Post <n>` are aligned at the right egde. I would like to align at the left; how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package provides parameters for label settings: `align=left` (or `right` or `parleft`). Just add it.

```
\begin{enumerate}[
  label = \Large\underline{Post~\arabic*},
  leftmargin = *,
  itemsep = 6ex,
  align=left% <--- added
]
```

and the list will look as you wish:

[image: output]